# SQL WHERE Field1 >= 1 OR Field2 >= 1 Allowing (null) Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query a database table and have the following WHERE clause on my query:

```
WHERE (QTY_ON_HAND >= 1 OR QTY_ON_ORDER >= 1);
```

I am wanting to return all results who have either quantity on hand OR quantity on order.

However, this is allowing records to return that have `0 QTY_ON_HAND` and `(null) QTY_ON_ORDER`.

Scrolling throug the results, it's even allowing `-1` (And other negatives) and `NULL`.

[image]

Here is the rest of the WHERE clauses:

```
    WHERE CHARGE_CODE = 'RETAIL' OR CHARGE_CODE = 'RETAILSN' AND
      LOCATION = 100 AND
      SPA_ITEM_ID LIKE '1%' AND
      (QTY_ON_HAND >= 1 OR QTY_ON_ORDER >= 1);
```

**Solution:**

Forgot the parenthesis on the first WHERE clause

```
CHARGE_CODE = 'RETAIL' OR CHARGE_CODE = 'RETAILSN'
```

needs to be

```
(CHARGE_CODE = 'RETAIL' OR CHARGE_CODE = 'RETAILSN')
```

Comment: is that the only filter or do you have more?

Comment: @vkp There is more, but they are all working fine and filtering correctly.

Comment: Try removing the brackets

Comment: post your full query..that might be the issue here

Comment: @MatthewFlynn that does not help, still not working.

Comment: @vkp edited into OP. They are all working fine. Only the questioned part is not working.

Comment: Is this the only one not working. If so, is it the only one with null values in the comparison

Comment: change your conditions to `WHERE CHARGE_CODE IN ('RETAIL','RETAILSN') AND
      LOCATION = 100 AND
      SPA_ITEM_ID LIKE '1%' AND
     (QTY_ON_HAND >= 1 OR QTY_ON_ORDER >= 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` operator has precedence over `OR`, so you need to use parentheses:

```
WHERE 
   ( CHARGE_CODE = 'RETAIL' OR CHARGE_CODE = 'RETAILSN' )
   AND LOCATION = 100
   AND SPA_ITEM_ID LIKE '1%'
   AND ( QTY_ON_HAND >= 1 OR QTY_ON_ORDER >= 1 )
```

Better yet using the `IN` operator:

```
WHERE 
   CHARGE_CODE IN( 'RETAIL', 'RETAILSN' )
   AND LOCATION = 100
   AND SPA_ITEM_ID LIKE '1%'
   AND ( QTY_ON_HAND >= 1 OR QTY_ON_ORDER >= 1 )
```

More on the matter explained in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/operator.htm#1003584).

Comment: Remember to use parenthesis on the last OR but not the first one... Thank you! Will accept as answer when I can.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW err... Wolfie... those are parenthesis ;) not brackets =[

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE
    CHARGE_CODE IN ('RETAIL','RETAILSN') AND
    LOCATION = 100 AND
    SPA_ITEM_ID LIKE '1%' AND
    (QTY_ON_HAND >= 1 OR QTY_ON_ORDER >= 1);
```

Hope It Helps!

Comment: Yepp.. Silly brackets! Thank you!